# Will the Velocity of an object change if it moves fast,close to speed of light?

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, reference-frames, observers

If an rocket moves with a speed of 0.5c. So, the speedometer in that rocket will show 0.5c. But there will be time dilation when someone sees it from the earth.
Then it's Time dilation will be

[image: Time Dilation Formula]

So, since the Velocity of the object is Distance Traveled/Time taken, and since the Time is increased, won't the Velocity of that rocket with respect of earth get reduced?

Comment: This time dilation is due to the fact that clocks in moving frame slows down. The time in earth frame remains same.

Comment: So, will the speed shown in the speedometer decrease?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tme dilation refers to time in the accelerated frame (the rocket). So a clock in the rocket will run slowly compared to a clock on earth. It is *us* who would measure the rocket as moving at 0.5c. The speedometer in the rocket could actually show a speed *greater* than that. From the POV of the crew in the rocket, their clock is running normally. It is the external space that gets contracted so they can move faster. There is actually no limit to the effective speed of the spacecraft - they can go faster than light!

Imagine a spacecraft going to Alpha Centauri 4 light-years away at 0.5c. From our perspective, it takes 8 years to get there. From your equation above, the crew experience a time of 6.92 years. So they have an effective speed of 0.58c.

If we increase the speed a bit, say to 0.9c, they take 4.44 years to get there (in our reference frame) but only 1.94 years in spaceship time. That's an effective speed of 2.06c.

Comment: The ship can't go faster than c, even in its own time-dilated frame. Space also contracts in the direction of travel, so while the ship makes the trip in 1.94 years, they will also measure the distance to Alpha Centauri as shorter than 1.94ly. If they take a radar measurement of the star while traveling at 0.9c (as measured from Earth) they will still measure the radar waves traveling at speed of c away from them, and thus the radar pulse will reach the star before they do. Their "effective" speed will still be less than c because they effectively travel a shorter distance.

Comment: @Asher. We're defining "effective speed" differently. What you are describing is the speed in the ship's reference frame. This is indeed <c. It's "real" speed measured in our reference frame is also <c. What I'm calling the "effective speed" is the distance travelled in the real world (4 ly) divided by the time the spacemen experience (2 years). That gives an effective speed of 2c -even though you can't measure that in any reference frame.